How to open a file from a docker containter with a command?
Using the docker vscode extension there is a way to open files from containters (and edit them).

Wondering if there a way to open a file from a container using a CLI command?
I am trying to do something like this:
code --folder-uri 'vscode://vscode-remote/docker/$container_id/usr/src/app/test_code'


Openning a file while you're inside the container? The question is not clear

You can find the rootfs of the container and run vscode on that path

Usually you don't: the host system can't directly see or edit files in a container, and vice versa.  Any change you'd be able to make this way would be lost when the container is deleted and recreated, which is an extremely routine action.  Not VSCode specific, but also see How to edit Docker container files from the host?
